# windows error handling

Tags: octave

The problem is that i'm running octave on windows or least I think that's the problem.
I'm causing an error on purpose and what I'm trying to do is get the whole error message so that I can grab the full file path from it. pwd() is returning the home directory, not the directory the program is running from.

I've tried error.file but apparently that's not part of the error struct.

so here is a full sample:

```
try
   err = make_error();
catch
   msg = lasterror.file;
   print(msg);
end_try_catch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've read the documentation wrong. The structure returned by `lasterror` does not have a field named `file`. What does have is a field named `stack`, which is also a struct, which does have a `file` field. So what you're looking for is `lasterror().stack.file`. See the manual section about [catching error](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Catching-Errors.html).

Also, `pwd()` returns the working directory, not the home directory. You are either doing something else wrong or it's a bug with the windows version.